# pdf2image Syntax Error: Invalid encryption key length Command Line Error: Incorrect password

Tags: encryption, pdf2image

I'm trying to convert a pdf to image using the python library pdf2image. With other pdfs the code it seems to work (I'm using the method `pdf2image.convert_to_path(PATH_TO_PDF_FILE)`), but on this it returns the following error:

```
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Error: Invalid encryption key length
Command Line Error: Incorrect password
```

I've already tried to read the pdf with the python library `pypdf`, and i've seen the pdf is encrypted. To be more specific, I have to install `pycryptodome`, without it PyPDF it's not able to decode pdf with 256 AES encryption, so I presume the pdf has this type of encryption that pdf2image is not able to decode itself.

Has anyone else ever had a similar error with pdf2image?

Comment: When you open the PDF in a viewer (e.g Adobe Reader, Preview etc.) does it require a password before showing the page content?